# A scheme of finite presentation over a filtered colimit of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I$ be a small [filtered category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtered_category).
Let $F\colon I \rightarrow CRng$ be a functor, where $CRng$ is the category of commutative rings.
We write $A_i = F(i)$ for $i \in I$,
$A =$ colim $A_i$.
Let $X$ be a scheme of finite presentation over $A$.
Then there exist an element $0 \in I$ and a scheme $X_0$ of finite presentation over $A_0$ such that $X = X_0\times_{A_0} A$?

Comment: You certainly know this is a special case of EGA IV, 8.8.2 when $X$ is quasi-separated. Do you ask whether this last condition can be removed ?

Comment: @QiL Dear QiL, By a morphism of finite presentation, I mean it is quasi-compact and quasi-separated and locally of finite presentation(this definition is adopted by the Stacks Project). I think it is nice to have a proof here, since this result seems not to be well-known(except by the experts).

Comment: You are right for the definition of finite presented morphisms (already in EGA). As the answer to your question is already in EGA with full details, I don't see why to present a proof here. What could be interesting is to sketch the ideas of the proof.

Comment: @QiL "As the answer to your question is already in EGA with full details, I don't see why to present a proof here." Perhaps I would agree if it was written in English. Anyway, a sketch of the proof is welcome.